# Numerical root-finding algorithms for rational polynomial functions?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots, rational-functions

Consider the polynomial equation

$$\prod_{i=1}^m (x - a_i) = \prod_{j=1}^n (x - b_j)$$

One way to solve it numerically is to convert it to a coefficient representation and use a root-finding method (like Sturm sequences) to solve the resulting degree-$\max(m,n)$ polynomial.

However, the above approach feels rather "dirty" to me, for reasons I can't really pin down.

What I'm wondering is, are there ***direct*** algorithms for solving such equations, i.e. (hopefully elegant) ones specifically designed for such pre-factored representations of a polynomial?

Comment: $a_i, b_i$ are integers?

Comment: @EugenCovaci: Nope, real numbers. (Or I guess I mean floats.) Although if there is only a special algorithm for the integer case then I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_polynomial#Yun.27s_algorithm

Comment: Just out of curiosity : anything special about the sign of the $a_i,b_i$ ?

Comment: @EugenCovaci: Thanks for the link! A few notes: (1) Unfortunately I'm not a mathematician so I don't really know much (even nomenclature) about polynomials in finite fields (or anything other than real or complex numbers), (2) I don't understand why they're raising terms to higher powers... why is $a_k$ raised to the $k$th power? and (3) From what I can otherwise understand, this looks an awful lot like Sturm sequences... are they basically the same thing, or is there a crucial difference? (not necessarily asking you to explain these... just explaining my thoughts as I read it)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Great question! Nothing particular about their *signs*, but in the particular scenario I had in mind, the equation is actually more like $\prod_{i=1}^m (x - a_i) = \prod_{j=1}^n (b_j - x)$ where $a_i \leq x \leq b_j$ for all $(i, j)$. I wasn't really intending to ask a question special to that scenario, but if you have a particularly intriguing answer for that, feel free to post it!

Comment: If the $b_j$ are large enough and $m<n$, then the left term is a small perturbation of the right term and the roots will be close to the $b_j$. A method like Durand-Kerner can use the structure directly as it only needs the values of the polynomial. It is also not too difficult to compute first and second derivatives from the product form, so that the usual methods from Newton to Laguerre should also work.